# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to delete record from employee database (Oracle) and I used PreparedStatement interface and its method. The code throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all
> variables bound

Here is my code

```java
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

dbURL = "jbdc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
username = "system";
password = "tiger";

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
System.out.println("Connected Successfully Database ");

String sql = "delete from employee where emp_id=? ";
statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

statement.setInt(1, 101);

int result = statement.executeUpdate(sql);

System.out.println(result + " record deleted");

connection.close();
System.out.println("Connection Successfully Closed");
```

Console

```
Connected Successfully Database 
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1169)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1615)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1580)
    at preparedStatementInterface.AllQueryPgm.deleteData(AllQueryPgm.java:79)
    at preparedStatementInterface.AllQueryPgm.main(AllQueryPgm.java:132)
```

Comment: **NEVER** use the `sys` or `system` tablespaces or you risk modifying critical parts of the database and making the database unusable. Instead, create a new user and use their schema.

Comment: It all looks like it should work. Does it work if you hardcode the bind variable `delete from employee where emp_id=101`? or if you use a named bind variable `delete from employee where emp_id=:emp_id` and `((OraclePreparedStatement) statement).setIntAtName("emp_id", 101);`?

Comment: employee table is NOT in the schema SYSTEM and very unlikely that the password is the same as the one of the HR schema, and in HR the correct table name is employees, so difficult to guess what you are trying to do exactly. For me the stacktrace doesn't correspond to the code, you should get a "table not found" if not no access at all because of the password.

Comment: You should use `statement.executeUpdate()`, not `statement.executeUpdate(sql)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer :- use statement.executeUpdate(), not statement.executeUpdate(sql)